# Using powershell, how do I create an api for an api management service with a version in path segment?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

I can create an api using powershell as follows

```
New-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $azContext -ApiId $apiId -Name $apiName -ServiceUrl "https://myapp-dev-apims.azure-api.net/${subDomainName}" -Protocols @("https") -Path $subDomainName
```

However, this cmdlet does not create a version. It appears I need to use

```
New-AzureRmApiManagementApiVersionSet
```

However, Its not well documented how to do this when looking to add a version using a path segment such as myApi.com/cart/v1.

When creating the version within the portal, it says "Versioning creates a new API. This new API is linked to your existing API through a versioning scheme. Choose a versioning scheme and choose a version number for your API:"

Do I need to create a new api using New-AzureRmApiManagementApi, again a second time? This is confusing.

The workaround to this is to just use the New-AzureRmApiManagementApi cmdlet to initially create the api, then go into the portal to MANUALLY create the version. But it would obviously be nice if the process of creating both the api and its version were repeatable in a script.

Using powershell alone, how do I both create an api, and the version in one script? Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> When creating the version within the portal, it says "Versioning creates a new API. This new API is linked to your existing API through a versioning scheme. Choose a versioning scheme and choose a version number for your API:"

It says  correct, if you `Add version` in the portal, it will create a new API, just in the UI, it appears like under the original API. You could check them clearly in the [resource explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/), there will be a `"apiVersion": "xx"`in the api version.  After you adding a version, it will add a new API in the `apis`, and automatic create a version set in the `api-version-sets`, refer to the screenshot. 
Per my test, the command `New-AzureRmApiManagementApiVersionSet` just create in the `api-version-sets`, and will not create in the `apis`, so you could not get what you want with it.

[image]

Also, I add version in the portal, and use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the request, it essentially call the same [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api/createorupdate) with creating a new API.

[image]

**Some Workarounds for you to refer**:

1.As you mentioned, create the api and add version in the portal manually.

2.Try to use [`New-AzureRmResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to create the api version.

3.Use the powershell [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api/createorupdate).

Answer (score 0):

To create a versioned API you first need to create a version set. You found the Powershell cmdlet for that. However, looking at `New-AzureRmApiManagementApi` it seems you cannot provide a versionsetid as parameter, which is needed to link the version set to the API.

With Powershell alone I don't think it's possible what you're trying to achieve, but what you could consider is using ARM templates.
These templates can be kicked off by Powershell and do provide the option to create an entire versioned API in one script.

For inspiration you could take a look at this blog post:
https://blog.eldert.net/api-management-ci-cd-using-arm-templates-linked-template/